# How can I echo og:video url, if the post has video content?

Tags: facebook, videos, open-graph

I would like to something simular solution like `is_home()` for videos.
If the post has video content, the php script write out the og video url (start with https of course).
In my example I imagine  like this way (I know this not working, this just a example):

```
<?php if ( has_video_content() ) {?>
<meta property="og:video" content="https://www.neocsatblog.info/jwplayer/player.swf?file=THE_VIDEO_ENCODED_URL&autostart=true">
<? } ?>
```

The video is a mp4 file (uploaded to the gallery), not a embed media (Yes I use short code for the media, the `[video]` shortcode is good for me.).
Is that possible somehow?

Comment: How does your post "have video"? Is it an oEmbed from YouTube, Vimeo, TED, etc.? Or is it uploaded to your uploads folder and you are using the `[video]` embed? Please read [ask] and [edit] your question with the necessary info.

Comment: I updated my post, I hope now is clear :)